# Hide URL when clicking on link?

Tags: javascript

I did this already, but now where I want to do it again, I cant find the solution to it <.<.

I simply want to hide the URL path when I load different pages.

Example: I click on `href='start.html'` and it shows `www.someurl.com/start.html`. I want it to always be `www.someurl.com`.

I don't want you to write the whole solution for me, a resource where I can read and find the solution would be great!

Comment: This is happily impossible.

Comment: It is partially possible with mod_rewrite (Apache Users), removing trailing slash. but not as he asks

Comment: It is possible, I've already done it one time, but I can't remember how it was done <.< . And I'm pretty sure I didnt use mod_rewrite... Isn't there a possibility via PHP or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrites.

http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

It ll be quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is what exactly you need. Simply you need to add '**/**' before each ***href*.

For example:

```
href='/start.html'
```

So that it will display as **www.someurl.com/start.html**

Comment: ? I think you misunderstood :D

Answer (score -1):

You dont really hide the URL, there are different way's to do this - one is to just use PHP to

```
include('site');
```

in this case you only see the `www.site.com` or `www.site.com/index.php`

Another would be to just use jQuery to load a site in a DIV element

```
$('#divId').load('siteLocation');
```

hope that helped!